# Ractive value not being set when select list is first loaded

Tags: ractivejs

I am using Ractive and have two select lists. The first select list lets the user select their country. If they select "US", Ractive will check for it and display a list of states for the user to select their state. For example:

```
<select value="{{country}}">
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
</select>

{{#if country == 'US'}}
    <select value="{{chosen_state}}">
        {{#states}}
            <option value="{{this.state_name}}">{{this.state_name}}</option>
        {{/}}
    </select>
{{/if}}
```

When this form first loads "Canada" is selected by default. Once the user selects "US", the states list shows up just fine. However, if I try to check the value of "chosen_state", it is set to empty rather than the first state in the states list. After I manually change the state, then and only then does the "chosen_state" value show as a state value.

Do I have to wait for the change event to be triggered by a manual event, or is there some way to make it so that as soon as the states list is rendered, it will update it's value automatically based on the first state displayed? It would be nice to not have to trigger a change event for every select list when it's rendered.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this requires a dirty check using updateModel. I made it so if the select field is changed, it triggers an event that calls updateModel on the instance to dirty check the chosen_state field.

Updated selected code:

```
<select value="{{country}}" on-change="countrychange">
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
</select>

{{#if country == 'US'}}
    <select value="{{chosen_state}}">
        {{#states}}
            <option value="{{this.state_name}}">{{this.state_name}}</option>
        {{/}}
    </select>
{{/if}}
```

And in ractive:

```
ractive.on('countrychange', function(event) {

    this.updateModel();

});
```

Alternate solutions might include observing the model for updates to the country then running this.updateModel() as well as just running updateModel on the required keypath which is more efficient.

Further documentation on this can be found at:
http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-updatemodel